# [SDK 44]Expo application throws TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined[0]')

Tags: android, react-native, expo, libphonenumber

I got this issue after upgrading to the latest Expo SDK 44 the android app didn't open with an error related to libphonenumber-js shown in the screenshot below:

[image: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined[0]')]

Environment Specification

```
Expo CLI 5.0.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043   
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.13.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.23.0-20200615.1913 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 8.3.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
      Watchman: 20210110.135312.0 - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\watchman.EXE
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: ^0.2.2 => 0.2.8
      babel-preset-expo: 9.0.1 => 9.0.1
      expo: ^44.0.0 => 44.0.5
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
      react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
      react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
      react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Maybe try clean and build project again - if you haven't tried already.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Do you mean I need to start it with expo start --clear option?

Comment: Yes - If that does not work, delete the node_modules folder and try install the packages again via npm install --save.

Comment: Yes I already did those steps and the problem persists

Comment: Please upload the code where you are using this module

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is related to the yarn.lock file I need to delete it and regenerate it again and everything works fine